# Unable to play .mkv files using vlc player

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and using vlc media player 2.2.4. I'm unable to play .mkv files using vlc player. While opening .mkv files it is giving some error messages like this.

```
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "VP90".
Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
```

Comment: There seems to be a solution at https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=131211#p438833. Try it and see if it works?

Comment: @edwinksl its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works with vlc 2.2.0 stable.

I removed my previously installed vlc 2.2.4 and installed vlc 2.2.0 using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

And now, it is playing .mkv files.

Comment: This does not work for me, so I just created another question:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/889356/unmet-dependency-libgles1-when-installing-vlc-in-14-04